# Consistent layout, different phone resolutions, with JQuery Mobile

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

If I have two different phone screen resolutions, the layout looks different.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHocg.png)

[What I get if I increase the resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKvqf.png)

What's an easy way to make it scale proportionally with JQuery Mobile?

Comment: use `%` when you are declare size

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with css media queries

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries